# How can I "cache" the effects of Intel OneAPI setvars?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, intel, icc, intel-oneapi

Intel's OneAPI distribution (which includes many components such as ICC) has a script named `setvars.sh`, which checks for the presence of various stuff, then runs components' individual scripts for setting environment variables. It takes over a second to run and prints some stuff to the terminal.

Now, I'm willing to run it *once*, but I certainly don't want to run it whenever I start a shell. How can I "cache" its results, in the form of the delta it adds (or removes?) from my environment before its invocation? So that I could just source a script with:

```
export PATH="whatever:$PATH"
export TBBROOT="whatever"
# etc. etc.
```

?

Naturally, I would need to re-run setvars.sh if my system configuration changed in any way, but I'm ok with that.

---

PS - It has to be said: OneAPI is the epitome of mis-naming. It's the never-going-to-be-used-by-anybody-other-than-us, one-of-many API.

Comment: How does it normally set vars in the parent shell's environment?  Do you have to `source` it rather than running it and `eval`ing the output?  If the former, probably you can just capture the result of `set` or `env` before/after and take a diff to see what env vars it set, and adapt that into something simple.  `set`'s output includes shell functions, not just env vars, at least in bash.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You have to source it. It would have been much nicer and robust of them to produce a script you can `eval`, but they don't do that... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it (bash assumed, this will work for other shells mutatis mutandis):

1. Disable sourcing `setvars.sh` in your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and whatever you run on login.
2. After logging in and being in a bash session, execute `env > /tmp/env_before.txt`
3. Source the `setvars.sh` script.
4. execute `env > /tmp/env_after.txt`
5. execute `diff /tmp/env_before.txt /tmp/env_after.txt /tmp/precache.diff`

Now, all the lines which have been *added* in the diff are new environment variable which were not set before. You can cache them as

```
export FOO="bar"
```

lines (make sure to add the parentheses, just to be on the safe side, if they're missing).

the lines which have been *changed* are changes to existing environment variables. Those will be very few and maybe even just `$PATH`. For those, your cache needs lines such as:

```
export PATH="/bunch/of:/intel/stuff:$PATH"
```

which prepends the Intel OneAPI entries to existing ones. You will need to check whether any entries you had before were actually *removed*, but I doubt this will happen. Anyway, do these lines manually; the other lines can probably be transformed all at once with a regexp.

The result is a shell script containing a few dozen `export` commands. Source that instead of `setvars.sh`, but remember to re-generate it whenever your system configuration / directory structure changes and when you update versions.